# Subgroup of $Z_{108}$ of order 9

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would in proceed in finding a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{108}$ of order 9 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would compute the number $a=\frac{108}9$ and consider the subgroup$$\{0,a,2a,\ldots,8a\}.$$